# Facing issue while deserializing xml Http Response

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize the HTTPresponse which is in xml format to an Object.

XML Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <NPIList>
- <NPI>
  <NPI>1003000118</NPI> 
  <EntityType>Organization</EntityType> 
  <IsOrgSubpart>N</IsOrgSubpart> 
  <OrgName>STEVEN ENGEL PEDIATRICS</OrgName> 
  <FirstLineMailingAddress>1700 NEUSE BLVD</FirstLineMailingAddress> 
  <MailingAddressCityName>NEW BERN</MailingAddressCityName> 
  <MailingAddressStateName>NC</MailingAddressStateName> 
  <MailingAddressPostalCode>28560-2304</MailingAddressPostalCode> 
  <MailingAddressCountryCode>US</MailingAddressCountryCode> 
  <MailingAddressTelephoneNumber>252-637-3799</MailingAddressTelephoneNumber> 
  <MailingAddressFaxNumber>252-633-0944</MailingAddressFaxNumber> 
  <FirstLinePracticeLocationAddress>1700 NEUSE BLVD</FirstLinePracticeLocationAddress> 
  <PracticeLocationAddressCityName>NEW BERN</PracticeLocationAddressCityName> 
  </NPI>
  </NPIList>
```

My code to retrieve the xmlhttp response and deserialize as follows:

```
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
      {
        var responseValue = string.Empty;

        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
          var message = String.Format("Request failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
          throw new ApplicationException(message);
        }
       Stream respStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NPIList));
        var resp = (NPIList)ser.Deserialize(respStream);

                    response.Close();
}
```

I have created my object class

```
   public class NPIList
    {
        public List<NPIObj> NPI { get; set; }
    }
```

I am getting the count as zero for the variable "resp".

Here is my NPIObj class:

```
 public class NPIObj
    {
        public string EntityType { get; set; }
        public string FirstLineMailingAddress { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string MailingAddressCityName { get; set; }
        public string MailingAddressCountryCode { get; set; }
        public string MailingAddressPostalCode { get; set; }
        public string MailingAddressStateName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string NamePrefix { get; set; }
        public string NPI { get; set; }
        public string OrgName { get; set; }
        public string SecondLineMailingAddress { get; set; }
     }
```

Can anyone please help me what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the [XmlElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute like:

```
public class NPIList
    {
        [XmlElement("NPI")]
        public List<NPIObj> NPI { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks bkdev.I tried with code snippet and its working fine. Buth the values are not copying to the NPIObj class properties.I have edited and added the NPIOBJ class as well.

Comment: thanks for sharing NPIOBJ class as well. you could then simply use the XmlElement attribute. pls see edit above

Comment: Glad it worked. would you mind [marking it as the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ?